# Let $X$ be a finite measure space. Can you choose an orthogonal basis of $L^2(X)$ so that the $L^1$ norms are uniformly bounded below?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a finite measure space. Can you choose an orthogonal basis of $L^2(X)$ so that the $L^1$ norms are uniformly bounded below? Also so that the $L^2$ norms are uniformly bounded above.

One thing I tried. By Holder we have that $\int |f|^2\leq (\int |f|^4)^{1/3}(\int|f|)^{2/3}$. Therefore if we can choose an orthogonal basis of $L^2(X)$ with uniformly bounded $L^4 $ norms, we're fine. Can we do this?

On $[0,\pi]$ with Lebesgue measure you can choose $\{\sin(nx),\cos(nx)\}$ where the $L^1$ and $L^2$ norms are constant.

Comment: Is there  a typo in the second quesiton? As it is, it looks silly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What do you mean? I only have one question.

Comment: Do you know what an orthonormal basis is ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes.

Comment: Do you know that any Hilbert space, in particular $L^{2}$, has an orthonormal basis?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Are you claiming that any orthonormal basis has $L^1$ norms that are uniformly bounded below?

Comment: @user953480: A better formulatino for the question would be: Does there exists an *orthonormal* basis such that the $L^1$-norm of the basis elements is uniformly bounded from below. (If only orthogonal is required then the answer is trivial: just rescale the basis elements of any orthonormal basis)